# Get Radio Group Value

Tags: php, radio-group

I am developing a page for multiple choice questions. User is only able to select an answer for each question. I can't seem to retrieve the value (1 indicates correct answer) of the radio buttons.

Here is structure of two tables that I use

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `question` (
`q_id` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`q_qstn_no` int(11) NOT NULL,
`q_text` varchar(300) NOT NULL,
`q_chpt` int(11) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`q_id`)
)
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `answer` (
`a_id` int(6) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`q_id` int(10) NOT NULL,
`a_text` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`a_value` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`a_id`)
)
```

**HTML form containing the radio group.**

```
    <?php
    ini_set('display_errors',1);
    error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);
    session_start();
    if(isset($_SESSION['tf1_sid']))
    {
    ?>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Untitled Document</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="ques_page_calc1.php">
    <p>Questions</p>
    <table width="900" border="0" cellpadding="4">
    <?php
    // db connect
    include("dbconn.php");
    // db query for questions
    $sql_q  = "SELECT q_id, q_qstn_no, q_text FROM question";
    $query_q = mysql_query($sql_q) or die("MySQL Error: " . mysql_error());
    // start loop for questions
    $rad2 = 0;
    while($data_q = mysql_fetch_array($query_q, MYSQL_ASSOC)){

    //        echo "<pre>";
    //        print_r($data_q);
    //        echo "</pre>";
    //        


        echo "<tr><td width='25' align='center' valign='top'><label><input name='q_no' size='1' type='hidden' value=". $data_q['q_qstn_no'] .">". $data_q['q_qstn_no'] ."</label></td>";
        echo "<td>". $data_q['q_text'] ."<br />";
        // db query for answers
        $sql_a = "SELECT a_id, a_text, a_value FROM answer WHERE q_id=".$data_q['q_id'];
        $query_a = mysql_query($sql_a) or die("MySQL Error: " . mysql_error());
        //$rad = 0;
        // start loop for answers
        while($data_a = mysql_fetch_array($query_a, MYSQL_ASSOC)){
            echo "<br /><table width='750' border='0'>";
            echo "<tr><td><label><input name='answer_".$rad2."' type='radio' value=". $data_a['a_value'] .">". $data_a['a_text'] . "</label></td></tr>";
            echo "</table>";
            //$rad++;
        }
        echo "</tr>";
        $rad2++;
    }
    echo "<tr><td><input name='Submit' type='submit' onClick='ques_page_calc1.php' value='Submit'></td></tr>";

    mysql_free_result($query_q);
    mysql_free_result($query_a);
    include("dbconn.php");

    ?>
    </table>
    </form>
    </body>
    </html>
    <?php
    }
    else
    {
    header("Location:s_login.php");
    }
    ?>
```

**The PHP file to get the value selected**

```
    <?php
    ini_set('display_errors',1);
    error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);
    // include db connection file
    include("dbconn.php");
    session_start();

    if(isset($_POST['Submit']))
    {   
$id = $_SESSION['tf1_sid'];
echo $id;
$correct = 0;
$ev_id = 1;

//db query to obtain i_id
$sql_i = "SELECT i_id FROM ins_stud WHERE s_id = '$id'";
$query_i = mysql_query($sql_i) or die("MySQL Error: " . mysql_error());
$data_i = mysql_fetch_array($query_i, MYSQL_ASSOC);
print_r($data_i);

// capture values from HTML form
if(!empty($_POST['answer_'.$rad2]))
{   
    foreach(($_POST['answer_'.$rad2]) as $ans)
    {
    echo $ans;
    var_dump($_POST);

    if($ans == 1)
        $correct = $correct + 1;
    }

    //echo $correct;

    // insert answer to table
    //$sql_eval = "INSERT INTO eval_set (ev_id, q_id, response, created) VALUES ('" . $ev_id . "', '" . $ques_no . "', '" . $ans . "', CURDATE())";
    //mysql_query($sql_eval) or die ("Error: " . mysql_error());
    //}
    }
    //  
    // insert result to table
    //$sql_result = "INSERT INTO result (r_score, ev_id, s_id, i_id) VALUES ('" . $correct . "', '" . $ev_id . "',  '" . $id . "',  '" . $data_i . "')";
    //mysql_query($sql_result) or die ("Error: " . mysql_error());

    //echo "Result: " . $correct . " questions correct.";   

    //header("Location:ass_result.php"); 
    }

    // close db connection
    mysql_close($dbconn);
    ?>
```

I thought it was the `$_POST['answer_'.$rad2]` that was causing the problem since I wasn't sure how to concatenate variables to name field. But now that's changed, there is still no output beyond `print_r($data_i);` line in the PHP file.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to give your radio group buttons different names. All of your choices will have a single name (say 'answer') and your PHP script will simply check for

```
$_POST['answer']
```

this will give you the selected radio button's value. So however many radio buttons you have ***for a certain question***, give all of them the same name and you're fine. This will also make sure that only one of the radio buttons related to each other can be checked.

Comment: If I omit the variable, it's impossible to retain the selected radio button for each of the question. For example, answering Q1 is fine but when I answer Q2, answer for Q1 is reset and so on. There would be only one selected radio button when there are, say, 4 questions on the page. The radio buttons are in groups of four, for each question.

Comment: sorry, I must've missed that you ARE actually giving the radio buttons the same name for the same question. It's only that you have several questions and hence have different names for each group.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it :) I took away the if(!empty...) and replaced it with these.

```
    for($i=1;$i<=$qno;$i++){
    $repStr = str_replace("1", $i, "answer_1");
    //echo "Question ". $i .": ". $repStr;
    $ans = $_POST[$repStr];
    //echo "". $radio ."<br>";

    if($ans == 1)
    $correct = $correct + 1;

    // everything before is FIXED :D

    // insert answer to table
    $sql_eval = "INSERT INTO eval_set (ev_id, q_id, response, created) VALUES ('MAX(ev_id)+1 ', '" . $i . "', '" . $ans . "', CURDATE())";
    mysql_query($sql_eval) or die ("Error: " . mysql_error());      
    }
```